# pop view off programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

I am trying to pop a view off programmatically but am having trouble.

```
import UIKit

class CreatePostViewController: UIViewController {

    var isAnimating: Bool = false
    var dropDownViewIsDisplayed: Bool = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        createDescriptionField()
        createLabels()
        createInputFields()
        createBackButton()

    }
    //More code omitted 

    func createBackButton(){
        let button = UIButton()
        button.setTitle("back", forState: .Normal)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.blueColor(), forState: .Normal)
        button.frame = CGRectMake(200,200,100,50)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        button.addTarget(self, action: "goBack:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(button)

    }

    func goBack(sender: UIButton){
        navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)

    }

}
```

I add this class from a another class like this:

```
import UIKit

class HomeViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        needCashButton()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func needCashButton(){

        let image = UIImage(named: "GlossyRoundedButton.png") as UIImage?
        let button = UIButton()
        button.setTitle("Do Job", forState: .Normal)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.blueColor(), forState: .Normal)
        button.setBackgroundImage(image, forState: .Normal)
        button.frame = CGRectMake(225,200,100,50)

        button.addTarget(self, action: "cashButtonPressed:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(button)

    }


    func cashButtonPressed(sender: UIButton){
        let findJob = CreatePostViewController()
        self.presentViewController(findJob, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

I read many other posts that suggested I just pop the CreatePostViewController with the line: `navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)` but that doesn't do anything when I click the button. Is there something I am overlooking here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your UIViewController is **NOT** in a UINavigationViewController (or it was presented modally), use this to dismiss it:

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

If you have it inside a UINavigationViewController, dismiss it using this:

```
self.navigationController.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

navigationController works only if you actually use Navigation controller :). So I would suggest to use something like this

```
let vc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: CreatePostViewController())
self.presentViewController(vc, animated: false, completion: nil)
```